# Searching Html tags Using PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-2

In my  rootfolder/xxx/header.php page have `<title>some text</title>`.

I want to search as like this html tags using php code.

That means i want change the text inside the title tag by using php code.

How can i do this?

This is the rootfolder/xxx/header.php file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
```

In my controller code:

```
    $data['title'] = "Launching Soon";
    $this->load->view('themes/header',$data);
```

This is the views/themes/header.php code:

```
<?php
    $this->theme_lib->get_header("xxx");
?>
```

The theme_lib is a library i loaded in the controller code:

```
 public function get_header($name = ""){
    include($name.'/header.php');
    }
```

I want to change the `<title>test</title>` as `<title>Launching Soon</title>`.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review the [Template Parser](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html) documentation it may prove useful. All you need to do is something like this:

```
<title>{title}</title>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: A better way to do this would be using the CodeIgniter template framework. See [the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I know hes using CodeIgniter. You don't need to use `<?php echo $title;?>` use this `{title}` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could have the titles stored in a SQL database and call them dynamically with PHP, update the database entry with PHP

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("mysite1", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM headers");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
$title = $row['title']
   }

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Then in the HTML part which is further down the page,

```
<title><? echo $title; ?></title>
```